# How do I revert to the previous commit without deleting the latest commit?

Tags: git, git-revert

Say I have 2 commits which I have already pushed to my remote branch.

- Commit A (31-May-2021)
- Commit B (30-May-2021)

How do I revert to Commit B without deleting Commit A? I just want to compare the result between these 2 commits.

Note: Code comparison is not needed. I just want to compare the output of Commit A vs Commit B

Comment: It actually impossible to delete a commit in git. So you shouldnt be afraid.

Comment: yeah a little worried since it is production code. Anyway, will try that out the 'riskier' option in my personal demo project

Comment: My point is, there is no risky way in git because you the commits are never deleted. There is no option in git to delete a commit, you can always get it back.

Comment: Just checkout commit B?

Comment: @JawadElFou: it *is* possible to lose a commit, but it takes some work—and the commit will come back if you connect your Git repository to another Git repository that has it. :-)

Comment: @torek I always thought that the way git is coded, never deletes commits, they are always there somewhere. Isnt what reflog does, give you a list of all commits included the one you "deleted". Is there a command to actually delete a commit that I am not aware of?

Comment: There is no single command to delete a commit, unlike (e.g.) Mercurial's `hg strip`. But if you have some chain of commits that is found only by the tip commit of branch name B, and you reset B to some point earlier in this chain, the commits past the new end-of-chain are no longer *findable* (except through Git's reflogs, if you have them enabled). The reflog entries eventually expire (or aren't enabled) and now these commits are eligible for garbage collection. The `git gc` command will eventually remove them.

Comment: Note that `hg strip`, in Mercurial, forcibly removes all commits "down-graph" of the stripped commit(s) immediately. Git's `gc` removes the same commits but only on the condition that they are truly unreachable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I strongly disagree with the other answers advising you to use `git revert`. This would actually really revert the changes introduced by *Commit A* and produce a commit on its own.

Since you want to have a look at the state at a point back in time, you could just checkout *Commit B* directly so you can inspect the contents. Afterwards checkout the original branch to go back to the latest commit.

```
git checkout $HASH_OF_COMMIT_B   # now you are in a detached head state at commit B
git checkout $BRANCH             # now you are back at the tip of the branch (commit A)
```

A lot of tools let you see the difference between two references directly without the need to checkout. On the command line, this could be done with [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff $HASH_OF_COMMIT_A..$HASH_OF_COMMIT_B
```

Comment: Yes, the *revert* in the question title leads people astray. Side note: the Git folks are trying to push people away from using the two-dot notation in `git diff`. Any `git diff A..B` can always be written as `git diff A B` instead, which actually makes the command *shorter*. The only place you need the two dots is if you omit one of `A` or `B` to imply `HEAD`: `git diff A..` has to be replaced with `git diff A @`, which doesn't make it any shorter.

Comment: Strongly agree. This is actually simple if you just want to compare the behavior of two commits. Just checkout the first, test, checkout the other, test.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I revert to Commit B without deleting Commit A?

You can easily use `git rebase -i <commit_hash>`

- Select one commit before commit B i.e. Commit C

> HEAD <- Commit A <- Commit B <- Commit C

- `git rebase -i <commit_hash_commitC>`
- Above command will list commits in your text editor that looks something like this:

> ```
> pick f7f3f6d Commit B
> pick a5f4a0d Commit A
>
> # Rebase 710f0f8..a5f4a0d onto 710f0f8
> #
> # Commands:
> # p, pick <commit> = use commit
> # r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
> # e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
> # s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
> # f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
> # x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
> # b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
> # d, drop <commit> = remove commit
> # l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
> # t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
> # m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
> # .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
> # .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
> # .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
> #
> # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
> #
> # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
> #
> # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
> #
> # Note that empty commits are commented out
> ```

- Remove line that represents Commit B then save and exit the text editor.
- Git will replay all the commits mentioned in the interactive editor and will stop, which will delete Commit B completely.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting **Commit B** will not delete **Commit** A. It will simply create **commit C** which will be undo everything you did in **Commit B**

```sh
git revert commit-b-hash
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git revert <Commit B>
```

> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).
> [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

---

However, if you just want to see the difference between the two:

```sh
git diff <Commit B>..<Commit A>
```

> Show changes between the working tree and the index or a tree, changes between the index and a tree, changes between two trees, changes resulting from a merge, changes between two blob objects, or changes between two files on disk. [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 0):

You can do an interactive rebase, remove the commits you don't require, and do a hard push on your remove branch.

```
git rebase -i     //opens interactive rebasing window

pick #commitID2 My commit 2
pick #commitID1 My commit 1    <- To unpick/remove this commit, using editor remove 
                                  line->

save the window.
git push origin branchname -f
```